# PSD file parsing in PHP extracting header information getting layers and exporting layers to png files

Tags: php, parsing, photoshop, psd

I am trying to read a .psd file in PHP. I've got complete header information from http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_72092 and I've got signature, version, channels, height and width, depth and color mode of the file.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$infoArray = array();
$fileName = "test.psd";
$fp = fopen($fileName,'r');

$infoArray['version id'] = @reset(unpack('n',fread($fp,2)));
fseek($fp,6,SEEK_CUR);

$infoArray['channels']      = @reset(unpack('n',fread($fp,2)));
$infoArray['rows']          = @reset(unpack('N',fread($fp,4)));
$infoArray['columns']       = @reset(unpack('N',fread($fp,4)));
$infoArray['colorDepth']    = @reset(unpack('n',fread($fp,2))); 
$infoArray['colorMode']     = @reset(unpack('n',fread($fp,2)));
```

How can I extract layers with name, height, width, x-coordinate and y-coordinate and then export those layers to a .png file?

Comment: Surely there is a developer out there who has already skinned this cat.  For example, check out this result found via Google - http://blog.easytech.com.ar/2008/01/14/slicing-photoshop-psd-files-with-php/

Comment: Full official format specification available from Adobe: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/. I've written a Java-based implementation using that, but it's a bit of work...

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have read that and mentioned that link above. I need to implement the specific functionalities in PHP.
Need to extract layers(name,height,width,x,y) and exporting those layers .png files.